# From where can I get list of all chat rooms in which I am participating?

Tags: support, chat

I have started a discussion as comments. The system suggests me to move it to chat room. Someone (including me) has moved it to chat room. Now, I am participating in chat room.

I left it. To join it again, I need to find and visit that question or answer on which there's a link to chat box. Can I get that link from other place?

Comment: @jokerdino That's the latest one. But, how did you get that?

Answer (score 4):

Drop into your [chat user profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/8479/sachin-shekhar) and look at the list of rooms you are currently participating in.

---

Searched for your name in the site chat rooms and the following turned up:

- https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3454
- https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3057
- https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2309
- https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3960/discussion-between-nominsim-and-sachin-shekhar

Comment: Thanks.. but, it has listed just recently used chat rooms. I am unable to find old chat rooms in my mind.

Comment: @SachinShekhar click on frequently in. Also, change user id & site domain accordingly. Fianlly, Deleted rooms are not visible, that's by design. *not sure about frozen ones*

Comment: @Sathya unable to find inactive ones there..

Comment: The result page has listed even those sites which I never even visited..

Comment: Hold-on.. is this really a result page for my name. Which kind of GET request is this in which URL doesn't contain my name?

Comment: Again, no.. I think frozen rooms keep conservation.

Comment: @SachinShekhar I would guess the room was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

In the **footer area of each StackExchange site**, there are some links in the first line. Here you'll find the link *chat* (I marked it with a read rectangle in the screeenshot):

[image]

This link leads to all chat-related functions, which are personalized.